# Why was Kirk promoted to Admiral?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, captain-kirk

Captain Kirk is a man of action, a bona fide space cowboy who famously made his career pushing the limits of the unknown. He is almost literally in love with his starship, the *Enterprise*. He has a notorious dislike for regulation and the orders of [his superiors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/156157/12857).

Everything about his character and history suggest that the ideal place for him to be is on the bridge of a starship, serving as Captain, deep out in uncharted space, where he has maximum autonomy and can best apply his skills.

We also know that there are several characters in Star Trek with similar situations who have declined promotions in order to maintain their positions as Captains and explorers. Most notably, Captain Jean-Luc Picard, as explained in [the question which inspired this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/156369/12857).

In Kirk's own words, to Picard:

> Don't let them promote you. Don't let them transfer you. Don't let them do anything that takes you off the bridge of that ship, because while you're there, you can make a difference.

However, confoundingly, Kirk himself was promoted from Captain to Rear Admiral in between the events of The Original Series and Star Trek: The Motion Picture.

The question is: why?

## Why was Kirk promoted to Rear Admiral given his legendary track record as an explorer, desire for the *Enterprise*, and dislike for authority?

I think we can all agree in retrospect that it was a terrible decision. He's clearly miserable without the *Enterprise* and takes her back at the earliest opportunity, then proceeds to waste away until the events of *Wrath of Khan*, and then is promptly demoted for insubordination.

So, [how could this happen?](https://i.imgflip.com/gt534.jpg)

Comment: The peter principle?

Comment: There is a non canon book that goes into this. Was 20 odd years ago that i read it will try and dig it out

Comment: @DoctorTwo Cool! That's probably the best were going to get, given the lack of canon material covering this era.

Comment: IMHO the *Generations* quote was Kirk expressing regret for accepting his own promotion.  At the time, he probably thought it would be good for his career.

Comment: @Kevin "It seemed like a good idea at the time would be an acceptable answer if it could be backed up evidence. Kirk never struck me as much of a career man.

Comment: There's a quote, Janeway I think or perhaps Sisko - *everyone* in Starfleet was a space cowboy back in Kirk's day. :-)

Comment: A comment now because I don't have the time to write a good answer. I think the assumptions behind this question are flawed. Kirk *now* (and in-universe in later shows) has a reputation as a bit of a cowboy, but if you watch TOS without this assumption, particularly the first season, he's quite a model officer. He doesn't have a problem with authority per se, but rather he occasionally has run-ins with flawed or self-serving authority. He probably wanted to follow his career path up to admiral, only to then find he didn't like it as much as he thought he would.

Comment: Interesting question. I always thought (assumed?) Kirk had to take the promotion or be discharged from Starfleet. Even in today's military, unless things have changed since I served, if an officer were passed over for promotion 3 times, they were automatically discharged. Starfleet could have such a rule, i.e. if they are passed over for or refuse promotion x number of times, they are then summarily discharged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Star Trek I novelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Motion_Picture_(novel)) sheds some light here (Roddenberry wrote this himself so it is canon)

> Kirk speaks via 'holocom' to his former year-long spouse, Starfleet flag officer Vice Admiral Lori Ciana (also revealed to be the second of the two victims in the transporter accident, along with Commander Sonak.)

So Kirk got married for a time to another officer and she promoted to Vice Admiral (it's unclear if this happened during or after). It's likely she influenced him to promote.

The non-canon novel [The Lost Years](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_Years) explains that this is indeed the case as [Ciana's role is pivotal](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Lori_Ciana)

> While Kirk didn't want to be tied to the Admiralty, Ciana was able to persuade him by promising to do everything possible for Kirk to command the Enterprise again when the refit was completed.

Comment: "He did it for a woman" is the most believable answer imo given Kirk's personality.

Answer (score 11):

### Why would Kirk accept a promotion?

Kirk gives us an answer in Star Trek II, the Wrath of Khan. He seems to be feeling his age and recognises that he no longer has the same vitality he had when he was a younger man. Additionally, the task he was assigned by Starfleet (training command-track candidates) is a plum assignment where he gets to pit his intellectual and strategic capabilities against the best and the brightest that Starfleet has to offer on a daily basis.

> **McCOY:** *Admiral? Wouldn't it be easier to just put an experienced crew back on the ship?*
>
> **KIRK:** ***Galloping about the cosmos is a game for the young, Doctor.***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Wrath of Khan](http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie2.html)</sup></sub>

No doubt Starfleet also gave him some guff about the fact that sharing his skills would help to save their lives and the lives of their crews.

> **SAAVIK:** *As I indicated, Admiral, that thought had not occurred to me.*
>
> **KIRK:** *Well, now you have something new to think about. Carry on.*

---

### Why would Starfleet offer him a promotion?

As regards the reason why Starfleet would offer a promotion to such a serial rule-breaker, this is covered in several Expanded Universe novels.

**It was in recognition of his sterling work on his 5 year mission.**

> *The rest of our tour of duty was routine; with Sulu’s and Chekov’s
> help, I was able to time our return to Earth five years to the second
> after we left. Admiral Nogura, now commander in chief of Starfleet,
> came aboard with Federation president Bormenus. In a grand ceremony,
> the entire crew was given medals, I was promoted to admiral, and
> Decker promoted to captain. We then had a reception on the shuttle bay
> hangar deck.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Autobiography of James T. Kirk](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Autobiography_of_James_T._Kirk)</sup></sub>

**They wanted to use his good name after a series of scandals.**

> *Nogura looked back at him. “To be perfectly honest, I didn’t want to
> come out of retirement, Jim. I did so because I was needed. People
> knew me, trusted me. My name generated confidence and respect. For
> that reason, I came back. Your name, Jim, whether you know it or not,
> generates that same confidence and respect.” He paused to let the
> words sink in. “I wouldn’t have put your assignment request on hold if
> I didn’t desperately need you.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek: The Lost Years](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Lost_Years)</sup></sub>

**Ultimately they offered him a *roving brief*, something sufficient to pique his interest.**

> *A hint of frustration crept into Nogura’s tone. “Dammit, Jim, listen to me. Being a starship captain requires a person to become a hell of
> a diplomat and think on his or her feet. And you were one hell of a
> starship captain. What if I made you an admiral without chaining you
> to that desk? If I made you a special envoy, put you in Admiral
> Ciana’s department as a troubleshooter?*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek: The Lost Years](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Lost_Years)</sup></sub>

Comment: Can nobody refute James T. Kirk to his face without starting "Dammit, Jim"?

Comment: @Machavity - A quick check of my Trek ebook library has found no less than 44 instances of people saying "Dammit, Jim!".

Comment: [Indeed](https://img.memesuper.com/4ff5fa5f2cd68195130c5adcb69c02c7_more-dammit-jim-dammit-jim-memes_284-285.jpeg)

Comment: @Machavity - "Damn it, Jim!" gives us another 22 instances.

Comment: Kirk was promoted at 37 and was 51 in Wrath of Khan. I don't buy that he was "feeling his age" in a Federation where humans can live to 150, especially not at the time of his promotion. The only reason he felt old in Wrath of Khan is *because* his career had become so boring: after defeating Khan he says "I feel young."

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - In the new trek film we see him experiencing ennui after just a couple of years of his five year voyage...

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - Kirk may have felt old from dwelling on thoughts of his son David.  It can't have been easy on Kirk over the years, staying away and knowing that they were missing out on important life stages together.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt a satisfactory answer could be found in canon. The probable answer is mundane military expedience. Higher rank is THE hallmark of success. There would also be the pressure to make room for younger officers to have their chance at command. No boomer captain wants to give up his sub, but he's gotta make room. Plus, age. You can't be a frontline officer forever. For reference, look at Captain Winters being promoted out of command of Easy Company in "Band of Brothers." He was a fighting officer, a good one, but he was promoted anyway. Easy suffered.